# parcel delivery scam

Tags: scams

I have given out my address and e-mail address to someone, who is sending a package to me, but i never met him. Now i received a mail i have to pay a huge amount like 1550 USD to get the package delivered. It is from Canada, but the provides email is gmail. not an official quicktrip parcel service. Anything to be done? Can they use my address to bill a more higher amount? shall i report it police?

Comment: How do they want the money? Cash, check, gift card? It is a scam.

Comment: i havent received information on how to pay, can they do something with my address?

Comment: @Ild They can certainly use your address as a "billing address" or "mailing address" when ordering things online, but if you haven't given them a credit card, you wouldn't get charged for it though.  If ALL they have is your address and email, I don't think it's enough to sign up for a new card in your name either.  So, not ideal that they know your address, but relatively low risk as long as you don't give them anything more.  Do make sure your email address has a secure password though, and even two-factor authentication if it's an option.

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, I would refuse the package and don't pay for it.  This could also be part of a larger scam once they've confirmed that there's someone at the address who will accept (and pay for) packages of unknown origin and content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One scam is that they take your money and deliver nothing.

Another scam is that they trick you into to giving them more banking details that they need, and they steal your money, and deliver nothing.

Another scam is that they deliver something and they steal it before you can get it inside the house, that item is contraband. Though why they would want your money first which would make many people decline the offer? Plus the shipping of contraband this way works best if you aren't expecting the package.

They shouldn't be able to get into your bank account with just the email, home address and name. Still you should contact the police, you might not have been the only one they contacted.

Comment: Can the scammer bill other stuff to my address? i will do it, thank you. i need to change some details as well. but unfortuantely a cannot the address..

Comment: *why they would want your money first which would make many people decline the offer?* scams often include a **deliberate** red flag, designed to filter out skeptics. They may not even care about that money if there is a larger scam in the works, they just care about testing how easy their target is. This is why the Nigerian Prince scams are still Nigerian Prince scams. They know skeptics will ignore an obvious and well known scam, and only ignorant or gullible people will accept it.